# Find the limit points of the sequence $a_n \ = \sin(\frac{n \pi} {4}) $

Tags: real-analysis

I know that I have to find some sub-sequences for each point, but how do I obtain a sub-sequence that does not alternate?

Answer (score 0):

This sequence is $1/\sqrt{2},1,1/\sqrt{2},0,-1/\sqrt{2},-1,-1/\sqrt{2},0,...$ and it just repeats from there. If you just build subsequences of the form $\{a_{8n+k}\}$ for eack $1\leq k\leq 8$, you will have a constant sequences which converge.